# Cannot connect to mysql server using IP Address

Tags: networking, ip, mysql, mysql5

I am trying to connect to mysql using an ip, but I am getting this error:

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (111)

I can connect using `localhost` instead of an ip though.

This doesn't work:

```
mysql -u ryan -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p
```

Yet this does work:

```
mysql -u ryan -h localhost -p
```

I was able to connect earlier today, then I installed iRedMail, then I uninstalled iRedMail, and the uninstall process did something to mysql I think so I reinstalled mysql from scratch using this:

```
apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-client-5.5 mysql-server-5.5
```

Then:

```
apt-get install mysql-server
```

After that I created my user, and now I can't connect using an IP address with both the new user or root user, but I can connect using `localhost`.

What is wrong?

Comment: Why do you want to connect with anything other than localhost unless your trying to allow remote clients to connect

Comment: I am trying to allow remote clients to connect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL in your configuration example is binded locally to the address localhost (or to be clear to the IP-Address 127.0.0.1). If you want to connect through your servers public IP-Address the access gets rejected.

You can see this by doing a `netstat -ln` or in new style with the command `ss`.

The removal and re-installation replaced some configuration files of MySQL. `apt-get purge` deletes configuration files, also for dependent packages. Typically MySQL is only binded to localhost on a new installation on Ubuntu so this looks like your config file of MySQL was replaced with the default. For other Distros I can't say anything about the default configuration.

If you want to use a MySQL-Administration-Tool (i. e. HeidiSQL) on your local machine you should not change the `bind-address` in the MySQL-Config to the public IP-Address. It's better if you use a SSH-Tunnel.

With the standard Linux-Command `ssh` this is very easy to achieve with `ssh -L 9999:localhost:3306 <servername>` where `9999` is the local port. You can also use the MySQL-Port 3306 as local port, but may this won't work if you have a local installation of MySQL. On Windows this can also be done with putty, just look on Google for "putty mysql tunnel", maybe [this](http://www.eaktion.com/blog/2011/12/25/connecting-access-to-mysql-through-a-ssh-tunnel-using-putty-and-port-forwarding/) tutorial should do it, but as I am a pure Linux user i cannot verify it.

Comment: but the first time I installed it, I used the default mysql configuration, and it worked fine.

Comment: Maybe there was a change in the default configuration. I can't tell because you didn't mention which distribution you are using. Another cause could be that the installation of another application reconfigured your MySQL configuration.

Comment: ah, I had to change `bind-address` from `127.0.0.1` to my servers ip address

Comment: Just deleted my comment because I saw your comment on Ramhound's question. But to clarify it: the main question is what do you want to do with the access from your home computer to the database? Administration of the database with certain tools? Data Management? Installation of an application which uses this database?

Comment: I want to to be able to use HeidiSQL

Comment: You shouldn't need to allow remote access to do that...

Comment: I don't know what SSH-Client you are using but I asume you are using putty. You can configure putty to make a local port forward and tunnel the mysql-port from the server to a local port on your machine. Maybe you want to look at this tutorial -> http://www.eaktion.com/blog/2011/12/25/connecting-access-to-mysql-through-a-ssh-tunnel-using-putty-and-port-forwarding/ or just google for "putty mysql tunnel".